# Why am I getting float is not iterable in this python snippet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

```
dist=[a,b,c,d,e]
spset=[1,3]
k=[]
for m in range(1,self.n+1):
    if m not in spset:
        k+=dist[m]
```

I'm trying to make a list k that contains the all elements of `dist` except the ones with whose indexes are in `spset[]`. What am I doing wrong? The error is:

```
k+=dist[m] 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Briefly: `a_list = [1,2]; a_list += [3]` results in `a_list` being `[1, 2, 3]`. If you have `3` and not `[3]`, you should use `a_list.append(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be the one stated by [@SuperSaiyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227884/supersaiyan). Also, here you have another possible solution more compact and simple:

```
[x for i,x in enumerate(dist) if i not in spset]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `dist[m]` is probably an `int`. You are trying to "Extend" a list through the `+=` operation. You probably want `k.append(dist[m])`.